# How to edit httpd.conf for www aliasing?

Tags: apache, apache-config

How do I setup Apache, editing the httpd.conf file I think, to properly alias www so my server directs the right way?

Comment: Sorry, this question is really hard to understand. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: It's a searching bonanza!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478173/htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-ssl-https http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973297/htaccess-for-www-only-redirection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685962/htaccess-redirect-non-www-to-www-preserving-uri-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943761/htaccess-redirect-non-www-to-www-except-for-a-particular-subdirectory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388976/htaccess-and-no-www

Comment: @Borealid, thanks for the links but they all seem to use .htaccess files... Should I not use httpd.conf file to do this?

And I am not sure what I am 'looking for' I just want if someone types in my domain, with or without www for it to go to where it should... All my code is in the non-www location. And media temple told me I had to edit the httpd.conf file.

Comment: @thatryan: An htaccess file is just another location for Apache configuration information.  You can do the same things in a `<Directory>` block in httpd.conf.

Comment: @Borealid Aha thanks for clearing that up, I thought they were two separate things ;)
I enabled mod_rewrite on my server, now just not sure where exactly the file goes...

Comment: This may help, I followed the instruction to install LAMP onto Ubuntu and when done I had a file structure like this image, 
http://img.skitch.com/20100715-jujg88f4xhb48p7t338bb3gpwi.png
So where would I put an .htaccess file? And do I need to keep the structure like that? How it is now, it redirects typing 'domain.com' shows the root index list, and 'www.domain.com' redirects to 'domain.com/domain.com/html'
Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `ServerName example.com` and `ServerAlias www.example.com`?  Note that those two names are different insofar as SSL certificates are concerned.